# Accessing taxonomy custom field values (Drupal 7)?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

I've added a new vocabulary to Taxonomy, and then proceeded to add several custom fields to that new vocabulary. In the taxonomy_term_data table, I see the values for the tid, vid, name, description, format, and weight fields. It also looks like there are now a couple of new tables in the database that are related to the new custom fields that I created for the new vocabulary (i.e. field_data_field_taxonomy_cip_code). The values in the new table are entity_type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id, language, delta, field_taxonomy_cip_code_value, and field_taxonomy_cip_code_format. There's nothing that I can see on the surface that would allow me to relate the two tables together.

How would I go about pulling the additional custom field values along with the new vocabulary values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, taxonomy_term_data.tid should relate to like field_taxonomy_cip_code_value.entity_id. In Drupal 7 Taxonomy terms are now entities.

Entity Ids and Bundle values in the database aer typically the database keys  used to relate "fields" between tables (as drupal "Fields" can be reused across multiple bundles).

Comment: Interesting. I certainly appreciate your quick (and correct) response! This gave me precisely what I was looking for :)

Comment: By the way, this little query is what I used to test your answer: SELECT fdftcc.field_taxonomy_cip_code_value cip_code,
ttd.name cip_desc
FROM taxonomy_term_data ttd, field_data_field_taxonomy_cip_code fdftcc
WHERE ttd.tid = fdftcc.entity_id
AND fdftcc.deleted = 0

Answer (score 8):

If you load the taxonomy term with [taxonomy_term_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7), you will get any custom field you added to the vocabulary.

I created a vocabulary to which I add a boolean field (field_test_boolean); I added a taxonomy term to that vocabulary, and then executed the following code. (22 is the taxonomy term ID for the taxonomy term I created.)

```
$taxonomy_term = taxonomy_term_load(22);
dsm($taxonomy_term);
```

The output shown by `dsm()` is the following one.

[image: screenshot]

If you want to get the field value for the language currently set for the field, you should use the following code.

```
$values = field_get_items('taxonomy_term', $taxonomy_term, 'field_test_boolean');
```

If you need to find the taxonomy terms for which the custom field contains specific values, you should use the [EntityFieldQuery](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) class.

```
  $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'taxonomy_term')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'fields_test')
    ->fieldCondition('field_test_boolean', 'value', 1, '=')
    ->execute();

  if (!empty($entities['taxonomy_term'])) {
    $taxonomy_terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array_keys($entities['taxonomy_term']));
  }
```

#### Note

As noticed in a comment, there is a bug that doesn't allow to use the `EntityFieldQuery` class for taxonomy terms. The code seems fixed in the Drupal 7 development snapshot, but Drupal 7.14 is affected by the bug.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response...this site has saved me several times already thanks to individuals such as you that are willing to share their expertise.

Comment: @kiamlaluno actually using `EntityFieldQuery` is not possible for `taxonomy_term` entity type because of a known bug, see [here](http://drupal.org/node/1054162)

Comment: @sepehr It seems the code has been already fixed on both Drupal 7, and Drupal 8. It just needs a new Drupal 7 version to be created.

Answer (score 0):

@kiamlaluno is right. And thereby you can join the fields to its entity in the database with:

```
SELECT td.* FROM taxonomy_term_data td
INNER JOIN field_data_field_taxonomy_cip_code f ON f.entity_id = td.tid AND f.entity_type = 'taxonomy_term'
```

Taxonomy terms are entities and their tid is their entity_id and the entity_type is taxonomy_term.